# Why is italicise not working in the overleaf code-\emph not working here

Tags: italic

I have written the following markup:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Title: SOP LaTeX Template
%% Author: Soonho Kong / soonhok@cs.cmu.edu
%% Created: 2012-11-12
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%
%% Requirement:
%%     You need to have the `Adobe Caslon Pro` font family.
%%     For more information, please visit:
%%     http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1712
%%
%% How to Compile:
%%     $ xelatex main.tex
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.75in,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec, color, enumerate, sectsty}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      YOUR INFORMATION
%
%      PLEASE EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINES ACCORDINGLY!!
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\soptitle}{Research Interest}
\newcommand{\yourname}{Tanushree Bhattacharya}
\newcommand{\youremail}{ug18tb@iacs.res.in}
\newcommand\action{\par\bigskip\noindent\itshape}

%% FONTS SETUP
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Path = fonts/, Ligatures={Common}]{adobe_caslon_pro}
\setmonofont[Path = fonts/, Scale=0.8]{monaco}
\setsansfont[Path = fonts/, Scale=0.9]{Optima-Regular}
\newcommand{\amper}{{\fontspec[Scale=.95]{Adobe Caslon Pro}\selectfont\itshape\&~{}}}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks,
pdftitle={\yourname - \soptitle},pdfauthor={\yourname}, unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=magneta,citecolor=magenta,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=[named]{WildStrawberry}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      Title and Author Name
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{center}{\huge \scshape \soptitle}\end{center}
\begin{center}\vspace{0.2em} {\Large \yourname\\}
  {\youremail}\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      SOP Body
% NOTE: Use \amper instead of \&
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{-1cm}
\section*{}
I am Tanushree Bhattacharya a final year master's student pursuing an Integrated Bachelor's and Master's Programme at the \emph{Indian Association for the Cultivation of Science, Kolkata, India}.
\end{document}
```

Why is italicise not working in the overleaf code?

Comment: (1) Please complete your minimal example so others can copy it as is. (2) I do not have your fonts and since the `\emph` text is italics without the fonts. you are either ignoring compilation errors (in which case anything can happen) or perhaps you have used a font that does not provide italics.

Comment: I have completed the example..Maybe now u can copy it and see where the error is

Comment: As mentioned as I do not have the fonts I cannot and as mentioned the code works when you outcomment the font setup macros. You may want to include the log file from your compilation of the example. You might also want to tag your question with the `overleaf` tag as some people keep an eye out for those.

Comment: I have commented on the fonts and now it works..Thank you